# WebP htaccess mod_redirect assistance

Tags: .htaccess, webp

I'm using ShortPixel plugin and trying to serve webp images via htaccess mod_redirect, but its not working. My host is SiteGround (Apache) and they have told me the following:

'The files are indeed loaded via .jpg extension but internally they are using the .webp format which you set. You can verify this from the response headers of the request.

This is normal behavior as your mod_rewrite code in the .htaccess file does not include redirect (through the "R" flag) and the images remain with the same URL. If you would like to have the same redirected, you should consider updating your .htaccess code.'

I'm not sure how to do this and would apprecite if someone knew the answer. My htaccess code generated through shortpixel is as follows (though I'm happy to delete / modify  as needed)

Edit: I'm not sure why but I cant seem to paste the code without stackoverflow telling me there's an error, so I've pasted it here

jsfiddle.net/gLewthsv

Answer (score 0):

@SilverBlack, the fact that the WebP image is served with the original extension (.jpg for example) is intended, because a redirect for each image would impact the performance of the page (doing another round trip to the web server for that image).
Could you please tell me what would be the reason/use-case needing this redirect, in the first place?
If you still need to do the 302 redirect, you should use:

`RewriteRule (.+)\.(?:jpe?g|png)$ %1.webp [NC,T=image/webp,E=webp,R,L]`

This worked on my test environment. Please also note that you're using an old version of the ShortPixel's .htaccess code, you can take the newer version from the plugin in res/img.
Then you should also remove the section marks `# BEGIN/END ShortPixelWebp` together with the option in Advanced settings, because otherwise the plugin will rewrite the .htaccess section if deactivated and reactivated.

Simon, CTO@ShortPixel